# how to explain attribs string in etherpad?

Tags: etherpad

In the etherpad database, I saw each pad has a structure like this

> {"atext":{"text":"\n*aaa\n*bbb\n*ccc\n*ddd\n\n","attribs":"*4|1+1*4*1*2*3+1*4|1+4*4*1*2*3+1*4|1+4*4*1*2*3+1*4|1+4*4*1*2*3+1*4+3|2+2"},"pool":{"numToAttrib":{"0":["author","a.bdUV2ZBYrjvQXE0D"],"1":["edanz","div"],"2":["insertorder","first"],"3":["lmkr","1"],"4":["author","a.Bjh7YjuSzfu8Y8C4"]},"nextNum":5},"head":39,"chatHead":-1,"publicStatus":false,"passwordHash":null,"savedRevisions":[]}

Anyone could explain the attribs string like above?

```
*4|1+1*4*1*2*3+1*4|1+4*4*1*2*3+1*4|1+4*4*1*2*3+1*4|1+4*4*1*2*3+1*4+3|2+2
```

I think there is a relationship between attribs and numToAttrib, but I don't know what it is, I will read the source code to find it.

Comment: I find some documents under etherpad/doc/easysync, or online url http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/source/browse/trunk/infrastructure/ace/easysync-notes.txt, but I need more to learn.

Answer (score 0):

[The Etherpad Changeset Library documentation should help](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/Changeset-Library)